# Delegated openid does not work on slashdot.org

Tags: openid, slashdot

I created an open-id recently on myopenid.com: http://axqd.myopenid.com/

And I own a domain, which reads 'axqd.net'. So I wrote down the following lines in the `<head>` section of index.htm page(`http://axqd.net` or `http://www.axqd.net/`).

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" />  
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://axqd.myopenid.com" />  
<link rel="openid2.local_id" href="http://axqd.myopenid.com" />  
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" />  
<meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="http://www.myopenid.com/xrds?username=axqd.myopenid.com" />
```

Then I can login with open-id `http://axqd.net/` successfully on many sites except `http://slashdot.org/`. It keeps telling me 'Invalid identity supplied'. But if I use open-id `http://axqd.myopenid.com/` instead of the delegated one, everything went fine.

Am I missing something here or is it just a bug of slashdot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slashdot has one of the buggiest OpenID implementations I've seen.  It's most likely not you.

Comment: Guess so. I just need some confirmation because this is my first time to deal with openid :P

Comment: If you want further confirmation, try your delegating OpenID at this interop testing site: http://test-id.org/OP/Sreg.aspx  If it works there, then you're doing it right.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I can login with http:// axqd.net successfully. But it said "login as http:// axqd.myopenid.com" instead of "login as http:// axqd.net". I don't know if that is what I should expect.

Comment: It sounds like you have it configured correctly then.  Yes, myopenid.com prompts you to log in with your "local id" rather than your "claimed id" when you use delegation.  I find it weird too, but arguably it may be the right thing.

Comment: frankly, myopenid's not-prompting-with-the-claimed-id thing is more than likely a holdover from OpenID 1.x, when the OpenID provider was entirely ignorant of what claimed ID was being used.  v2.0 passes this information to the provider, and would probably make better for more consistent user experience.  ...unless you still use some v1.x relying parties.  Then you're just doomed to confusion.